# KDE Plasma doesn't start (black screen) after upgrading Debian10->11

Tags: debian, kde, upgrade, plasma

I upgraded from Debian 10 to 11. After completing the upgrade – which had problems due to lack of disk space (there should have been enough), some rkhunter config and unattended-upgr blocking konsole commands – I rebooted.

The first strange thing was that the initial boot screen asking for the grub password was red and looked a bit strange instead of blue but quickly changed back to the blue one. The second problem was that after logging in I only have a black screen (with some windows on top). This is because plasmashell isn't running (the only thing that runs is `startplasma-x11`) so I started it with `kstart5 plasmashell`. However, it crashes right after it seems to have fully loaded (with the desktop and the task bar showing). How to solve this? The full output is:

```
Omitting both --window and --windowclass arguments is not recommended

kf.coreaddons: Expected JSON property "X-Plasma-ContainmentCategories" to be a string list. Treating it as a list with a single entry: "panel" org.kde.plasma.desktop.defaultPanel
kf.coreaddons: Expected JSON property "X-Plasma-ContainmentCategories" to be a string list. Treating it as a list with a single entry: "panel" org.kde.plasma.desktop.appmenubar
kf.coreaddons: Expected JSON property "X-Plasma-ContainmentCategories" to be a string list. Treating it as a list with a single entry: "panel" org.kde.plasma.desktop.emptyPanel
kf.plasma.quick: Applet preload policy set to 1
Cyclic dependency detected between "file:///usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/qml/org/kde/kirigami.2/styles/org.kde.desktop.plasma/Units.qml" and "file:///usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/qml/org/kde/kirigami.2/styles/org.kde.desktop.plasma/Units.qml"
qt.svg: <input>:406:376: Could not add child element to parent element because the types are incorrect.
qt.svg: <input>:407:130: Could not add child element to parent element because the types are incorrect.
qt.svg: <input>:408:130: Could not add child element to parent element because the types are incorrect.
qt.svg: <input>:408:393: Could not add child element to parent element because the types are incorrect.
qt.svg: <input>:409:130: Could not add child element to parent element because the types are incorrect.
qt.svg: <input>:410:129: Could not add child element to parent element because the types are incorrect.
qt.svg: <input>:411:129: Could not add child element to parent element because the types are incorrect.
qt.svg: <input>:412:129: Could not add child element to parent element because the types are incorrect.
qt.svg: <input>:413:129: Could not add child element to parent element because the types are incorrect.
qt.svg: <input>:413:379: Could not add child element to parent element because the types are incorrect.
qt.svg: <input>:413:631: Could not add child element to parent element because the types are incorrect.
trying to show an empty dialog
file:///usr/share/plasma/shells/org.kde.plasma.desktop/contents/views/Desktop.qml:146:19: QML Loader: Binding loop detected for property "height"
file:///usr/share/plasma/shells/org.kde.plasma.desktop/contents/views/Desktop.qml:146:19: QML Loader: Binding loop detected for property "height"
trying to show an empty dialog
file:///usr/share/plasma/shells/org.kde.plasma.desktop/contents/views/Desktop.qml:146:19: QML Loader: Binding loop detected for property "height"
file:///usr/share/plasma/shells/org.kde.plasma.desktop/contents/views/Desktop.qml:146:19: QML Loader: Binding loop detected for property "height"
libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
kf.coreaddons: KDirWatch: "/usr/share/desktop-base/homeworld-theme/wallpaper" is a directory. Use addDir!
kf.coreaddons: KDirWatch: "/usr/share/desktop-base/futureprototype-theme/wallpaper" is a directory. Use addDir!
kf.coreaddons: KDirWatch: "/usr/share/desktop-base/futureprototype-theme/wallpaper-withlogo" is a directory. Use addDir!
kf.coreaddons: KDirWatch: "/usr/share/desktop-base/joy-theme/wallpaper" is a directory. Use addDir!
kf.coreaddons: KDirWatch: "/usr/share/desktop-base/joy-inksplat-theme/wallpaper" is a directory. Use addDir!
kf.coreaddons: KDirWatch: "/usr/share/desktop-base/joy-theme/lockscreen" is a directory. Use addDir!
kf.coreaddons: KDirWatch: "/usr/share/desktop-base/lines-theme/wallpaper" is a directory. Use addDir!
kf.coreaddons: KDirWatch: "/usr/share/desktop-base/lines-theme/lockscreen" is a directory. Use addDir!
kf.coreaddons: KDirWatch: "/usr/share/desktop-base/moonlight-theme/wallpaper" is a directory. Use addDir!
kf.coreaddons: KDirWatch: "/usr/share/desktop-base/moonlight-theme/lockscreen" is a directory. Use addDir!
kf.coreaddons: KDirWatch: "/usr/share/wallpapers/Next" is a directory. Use addDir!
kf.coreaddons: KDirWatch: "/usr/share/desktop-base/softwaves-theme/wallpaper" is a directory. Use addDir!
kf.coreaddons: KDirWatch: "/usr/share/desktop-base/softwaves-theme/lockscreen" is a directory. Use addDir!
kf.coreaddons: KDirWatch: "/usr/share/desktop-base/spacefun-theme/wallpaper" is a directory. Use addDir!
libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
Plasma Shell startup completed
qml: disabling redshift
qml: renderModeString: 
qml: disabling redshift
qml: onLoaded
Connecting to deprecated signal QDBusConnectionInterface::serviceOwnerChanged(QString,QString,QString)
file:///usr/share/plasma/plasmoids/org.kde.panel/contents/ui/main.qml:30:1: QML DropArea (parent or ancestor of QQuickLayoutAttached): Binding loop detected for property "minimumWidth"
Both point size and pixel size set. Using pixel size.
Both point size and pixel size set. Using pixel size.
Both point size and pixel size set. Using pixel size.
trying to show an empty dialog
trying to show an empty dialog
trying to show an empty dialog
Cyclic dependency detected between "file:///usr/share/plasma/plasmoids/org.kde.plasma.notifications/contents/ui/global/Globals.qml" and "file:///usr/share/plasma/plasmoids/org.kde.plasma.notifications/contents/ui/NotificationHeader.qml"
file:///usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/qml/org/kde/plasma/extras/PlasmoidHeading.qml:56:5: Unable to assign [undefined] to int
Plasma Shell startup completed
Plasma Shell startup completed
trying to show an empty dialog
file:///usr/share/plasma/shells/org.kde.plasma.desktop/contents/views/Desktop.qml:146:19: QML Loader: Binding loop detected for property "height"
file:///usr/share/plasma/shells/org.kde.plasma.desktop/contents/views/Desktop.qml:146:19: QML Loader: Binding loop detected for property "height"
KAStatsFavoritesModel::setFavorites is ignored
Entry is not valid "applications:seahorse.desktop" QSharedPointer(0x563b9bdb07d0)
Entry is not valid "applications:seahorse.desktop" QSharedPointer(0x563b9bd267e0)
file:///usr/share/plasma/plasmoids/org.kde.plasma.kickoff/contents/ui/FullRepresentation.qml:356: ReferenceError: headerSeparator is not defined
trying to show an empty dialog
qml: clearing connected sources, stop source was: killall redshift; redshift -x
qml: enabling redshift with command: redshift [...]
libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
libpng warning: known incorrect sRGB profile
libpng warning: profile matches sRGB but writing iCCP instead
file:///home/username/.local/share/plasma/plasmoids/org.kde.plasma.eventcalendar/contents/ui/TimerView.qml:31:13: QML ToolButton: Detected anchors on an item that is managed by a layout. This is undefined behavior; use Layout.alignment instead.
file:///home/username/.local/share/plasma/plasmoids/org.kde.plasma.eventcalendar/contents/ui/TimerView.qml:87:13: QML ColumnLayout: Detected anchors on an item that is managed by a layout. This is undefined behavior; use Layout.alignment instead.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to remove (or move) the `/home/username/.local/share/plasma/plasmoids/org.kde.plasma.eventcalendar/` folder (e.g. by running `dolphin ~/.local/share/plasma/plasmoids/`) and to create a bug report (which I'll do soon). It can then be started with `kstart5 plasmashell`.

Comment: This occurred on of my Debian 10 machines but not another with almost the same setup so I suspect it was caused by the upgrade breaking before completing (I ran full-upgrade right away on the machine on which this worked...even though now the audio isn't working there anymore unlike with the machine upgraded first and asked about).

Comment: Late but the bug report is [here](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=458634).